# How to permit strong params for nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I'm getting a `Unpermitted parameters: latitude, longitude, address` error in the log when I try to accept nested attributes from a form. The exact params look like:

```
{  
  "widget"=> {
    "owner"=>"100", 
    "name"=>"Widget Co", 
    "locations_attributes" => {
      "0"=> {
        "latitude"=>"51.4794259", 
        "longitude"=>"-0.1026201", 
        "address"=>"123 Fake Street"
      }
    }
  },
  "commit"=>"Create Supplier", 
  "action"=>"create", 
  "controller"=>"widgets"
}
```

A widget `has_many` locations, and a location `belongs_to` a widget. The params are set in the `widgets_controller` which I thought would permit everything under "0", but doesn't seem to?

```
def widget_params
  params.require(:widget).permit(:owner, :name, locations_attributes: [{"0" => []}])
end
```

Is there a working / better way to accept these params?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a try with this

```
def widget_params
  params.require(:widget).permit(:owner, :name, locations_attributes: [:id, :latitude, :longitude, :address])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your widgets_params code should be:

```
def widget_params
  params.require(:widget).permit(:owner, :name, locations_attributes: [:latitude, :longitude, :address])
end
```